# do not call updateAppWidget at widget screen adding (at first time)

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, onupdate

When my application starts, I call activity with listview and first item to it. my widget adds new one item to the listView in the onUpdate():

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

           RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);
           myString = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes); 

           Intent active = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
           active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

           Intent archive = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
           archive.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           archive.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_ARCHIVE);

           String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
           active.putExtra("msg", q);
           if (getQuotes(context).size()>1)
           remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, q);

           PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
           PendingIntent archivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, archive,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

           remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetFrameLayout, archivePendingIntent);
           Time now = new Time();
           now.setToNow();
           String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

           // adding new item to the listView
           saveQuote(context, q, mydate);
           appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
      }
```

and when user adds widget to the screen, one more items adds to list automatically. But I need to add it after `android:updatePeriodMillis` period has passed. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it something like this: created two methods with SharedPreferences, where I put flags of what method is executes now:

```
 private void setWidgetActive(Context context, boolean active,String field){
        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(field, active);
        edit.commit();
    }
  private boolean getWidgetActive(Context context, String field)
  {
      Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
    return prefs.getBoolean(field, false);
  }
```

then, my onEnabled method:

```
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        setWidgetActive(context,true, WIDGET_ACTIVE);
    }
```

in onUpdate method:

```
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
      setWidgetActive(context,true, WIDGET_UPDATE);
      if (getWidgetActive(context, WIDGET_UPDATE) & !getWidgetActive(context, WIDGET_ACTIVE))
       {
           myString = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes); 
           q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
           mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
           saveQuote(context, q, mydate);
       }
       else
       {
          ArrayList<Quote> importList = getQuotes(context);
          q = importList.get(importList.size() - 1).getText();
          mydate = importList.get(importList.size() - 1).getDate();
          setWidgetActive(context,false, WIDGET_ACTIVE);

       }
}
```

so if widget was added just now, getWidgetActive(context, WIDGET_ACTIVE) returns true and I get last added field of database and send it to the TextView of the widget. And in that case, when defined time has passed, I get new random stting from array and save in database and also send to the TextView.